# Php - add associative array to new array only if all values aren't empty

Tags: php, arrays, loops, associative-array

I am looping over an associative array in php, and want to add the array to a new array but only if all the values (either $name or $value) in the key-value pairs aren't empty. The array I'm looping over looks like this:

```
$arr = ['label' => $name, 'value' => $value]
```

I have tried the following:

```
$arr = ['label' => $name, 'value' => $value]

$filtered = [];

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
            if(!empty($val)) {
                $customAttrsFiltered[] = [$arr];
            }
         }
```

but it was not successful.
Any help appreciated

Comment: Please show us your best attempt (code) and where you're stuck. Although this is not the first question you've asked, you might need a refresher, please read [ask]

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

$array = [
    [ 'label' => 'Label 1', 'value' => 'Value 1' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Label 2', 'value' => '' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Label 3', 'value' => 'Value 3' ],
    [ 'label' => 'Label 4', 'value' => '' ],
];

$new_array = array_filter( array_map( function( $item ) {
    if ( empty( $item['value'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    return $item;
}, $array ) );

print_r( $new_array );
```

You should get something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Label 1
            [value] => Value 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Label 3
            [value] => Value 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```php
$arr = ['label' => $name, 'value' => $value]

$filtered = [];

$hasEmptyValue = false;
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if(empty($val)) {
        $hasEmptyValue = true;
    }
}
if(!$hasEmptyValue) {
    $customAttrsFiltered[] = [$arr];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am a big fan of array methods so will go with the answer above but still thank you very much